# Making selection sort with and without enumerate

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I was trying to create a function for selection sort but had some issues when I tried to use enumerate.

Was hoping somebody could help me understand why the top function is working but the bottom one isn't. Thanks!

Working:

```
def selection_sort(arr):
for x in range(len(arr)):           
    current_min = [x,arr[x]]
    for i in range(x,len(arr)): 
        if arr[i] < current_min[1]:
            current_min = [i,arr[i]]
    temp = arr[x]
    arr[x] = current_min[1]
    arr[current_min[0]] = temp
print arr
```

Not Working:

```
def selection_sort(arr):
for x in range(len(arr)):                   
    current_min = [x,arr[x]]        
    for i, v in enumerate(arr, x):
        if v < current_min[1]:
            current_min = [i,v]
    temp = arr[x]
    arr[x] = current_min[1]
    arr[current_min[0]] = temp
print arr
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range(x,len(arr)):
    arr[i]
```

will start from index x and go all the way up to len(arr)-1. Let's assume x is 2 and the array has length 5. Effectively, you'll access the elements

```
arr[2]
arr[3]
arr[4]
```

However,

```
for i, v in enumerate(arr, x):
    i, v
```

will iterate through all elements, but the indices will start from x, so you will get

```
2, arr[0]
3, arr[1]
4, arr[2]
5, arr[3]
6, arr[4]
```

To fix that, you want to iterate over the array from starting at position x, so change the above line to

```
for i, v in enumerate(arr[x:], x):
```

Comment: Yep, that fixed it and makes sense. Thanks you!!